# Failed to create task for type sonar

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have written ant build script to run sonar. But, am getting below issue while building:

> Error Message :
>       BUILD FAILED
>       C:\sonar\workspace\Sample\build.xml:12: Problem: failed to create task or type sonar
>       Cause: The name is undefined.
>       Action: Check the spelling.
>       Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
>       Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

build.xml:

```
<project name="SampleSonar" default="sonar" basedir=".">
    <target name="cleanclasses">
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin/temp" classpath="" debug="on"/>
    </target>
    <target name="sonar" depends="cleanclasses">
          <!-- Add the Sonar task -->
        <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
            <classpath path="C:\apache-ant-1.7.1\lib\sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar" />
        </taskdef>
        <sonar>
            <property name="sonar.sources" value="src" />
            <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="Sample" />
            <property name="sonar.projectName" value="Sonarqube Sample Project" />
            <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0" />
            <property name="sonar.language" value="java" />
            <property name="sonar.sources" value="src" />
            <property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://localhost:9000" />
            <property name="temp.dir" value="/src/temp" />
        </sonar>            
    </target>
</project>
```

I am using :

> java: 1.6
>
> sonar ant task : 2.2
>
> sonarqube : 4 ant : 1.7.1

How can I create ant task to run sonar ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Ant), task is `<sonar:sonar>` but not `<sonar>`.

Comment: <sonar:sonar> this is also not working... getting sonar:sonar doesn't support the nested "property" element error

Comment: That does not relate to the task namespace. <property> is provided by Ant core and is not a field of sonar task.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your script which can be solved as following:

- add a namespace to the sonar task (e.g. ´sonarns´ or just ´sonar´)
- define the ant properties outside the the sonar task tag

Your sonar target should look like that:

```
<target name="sonar" depends="cleanclasses">
      <!-- Add the Sonar task -->
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
        <classpath path="C:\apache-ant-1.7.1\lib\sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar" />
    </taskdef>
    <property name="sonar.sources" value="src" />
    <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="Sample" />
    ...
    <sonarns:sonar xmlns:sonarns="antlib:org.sonar.ant" />
</target>
```